# Uploading a File from local hard drive to a folder on a website from a winform using WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file-upload, webclient

When i choose a file from the OpenFileDialog, then it takes the FileName as "D:\myfile.txt".But i want only the filename, not the drive or path, so that i could pass it to the WebClient object.

How to get only the filename excluding the rest of the path of the local drive.

Also, what **DESTINATION **URI**** shall i give to the WebClient object.

my web url is : www.myweb.com
I want to upload in the folder: www.myweb.com\products\productinvoices\

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Image Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|(*.png)|*.png|" +
                            "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1; // set on Word Files (*.doc)

        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
        button2.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();


        myWebClient.UploadFile(@"**www.myweb.com\products\productinvoices\", openFileDialog1.FileName**);           

}
```

Its giving error : Could not find a part of the path..............

Comment: You should ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can't upload files to websites like that. There either has to be some service (ASP.NET or PHP or whatever) that accepts the file or you have to use FTP.

On your first question, to get just the file from full path, use the [`Path.GetFileName() method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx).

Comment: @svick : you mean there's no way using .NET?

Comment: I mean there's no way using .Net or anything else if the server doesn't support it. You either have to use FTP (or similar protocol) or have a server-side application that handles the uploads (written in ASP.NET or PHP or any other web application framework).

Comment: @svick : my website is hosted on a linux server. so what would be the URI ?

Comment: @sqlchild, you have to configure your server, there isn't any URI that would work if it's not configured to do that.

Comment: how to configure my server? i logged into my server, and then went to FTP Anonymous....here is checked both options....Allow anonymous access to ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com & .......Allow anonymous uploads to ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com/incoming

Comment: also, i went to ----> FTP Accounts--->and created a new account, then checked its details where it shows : FTP Server: ftp.mywebsite.com

Comment: i can open from filezilla , but not from a browser, is this due to my server being a linux server, also, so will i not be able to upload using .net?

Comment: @sqlchild, that's beyond this question, you should ask a new one

Answer (score 0):

You should create some PHP files for handling your upload rather than using .NET Uploader

Comment: He has a desktop application that doesn't work and you're suggesting to use PHP *instead*? That doesn't make sense to me. Using PHP (or ASP.NET or …) *in addition* would be a solution, though.

Comment: @Aditya, what? The server has no way of knowing what language the program doing the uploading is written in.

Comment: What i mean is you have to create uploader form and then you fill the form with your software and then you submit the file. The PHP will do the rest of the method to upload. I agree with your FTP statements.

Comment: @svick : sir, what to do please help

Comment: @sqlchild, have you seen my answer?

Comment: @svick: sir, there's no way using .net. my server on which my web site is a linux server

Comment: @sqlchild, access using FTP or handle the Upload with PHP and use the Desktop app interact with the PHP Page

Comment: @Aditya Avaga Purwa : HOW TO access using FTP , what would be the URI to pass it to the WebClient object

Comment: i want to upload using .NET. is it impossible?

Comment: You can create FTP Connection using .NET, and of course it possible. You can use FtpWebRequest class.

Comment: but sir, what would be the URI ?

Comment: also, please help me with the code , how to use FtpWebRequest class to make connection using FTP and upload a file

Comment: First you have to set the Network Credentials with your FTP Username and FTP Password. The URL is your server ftp address.

Comment: sir , its done sir, thanks a lot sir, for your great help...........am greatly obliged for your great favor, also , this would upload image files also?

Comment: and what about size? will it upload a file of any size

Comment: @sqlchild, you're welcome. FTP can upload all files type permitted by the server. And for sizing, its depend on server limitation. If you want to limit the size of files, use it on your .NET code to check the files size given.